# Kendo grid filter - how to use an "OR" filter

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've been tasked with creating an OR filter for a Kendo grid (which was implemented by another development team, who have since left). Basically, we have ID numbers. We can use the code (below) to filter, either to a single record or ones "containing" and so on (all the standard options).

However, what we want is a filter whereby the user can paste in a string of ID numbers (so something like 123,456,789 etc - could be hundreds) and the filter would bring those up.

Currently our code for the filter is:

```
{ field: "id", title: "ID Number",
                                filterable: {
                                    cell: {
                                        template: function (args) {
                                            args.element.kendoNumericTextBox({
                                                format: "#",
                                                decimals: 0,
                                                spinners: false
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, using my own filter which is really complex and in a lot of different places. But, if anyone finds it useful...

Following is in my js file:

```
    self.init = function () {
        var FilterToUse = new String($("#MyFilter").val());
        self.filterIDs = FilterToUse !== "" ? FilterToUse.split(" ").map(Number) : [];
    }

    self.filterMyFilter = function () {
        return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var promises = [];
            promises.push(self.init());
            RSVP.all(promises)
                .then(function (posts) {
                    var selectedIdsToFilter = self.filterIDs.join(",");
                    $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read({ SelectedIds: selectedIdsToFilter });
                });
        });
    };
```

With self.filterIDs being defined earlier:

```
self.filterIDs = [];
```

And MyGrid being my grid, and MyFilter being an input box where I can just paste in my IDs (123 456 789 etc).

Then we use the module, and make sure we add this to the code that creates that grid:

```
string selectedIds = Request.Form["SelectedIds"];  // SelectedIds comes from paste IDs
List<long> selectedIdList = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedIds) == false ? selectedIds.Split(',').Select(long.Parse).ToList() : null;
```

And, so we can filter on it...

```
if (selectedIdList != null)
{
    where = where.And(w => selectedIdList.Contains(w.Id));
}
```